# Update table column rows with top dimension values and rest as others

Tags: sql

`I have fact table, say main_table with 30 OS Types and values for each. The values in table look some thing like below:

```
DATE OS_TYPE MEASURE1 MEASURE2
------------------------------


09/01/2013   WI8     
09/01/2013   WI7     
09/01/2013   WXP     
09/01/2013   MAC     
09/01/2013   WI8     
09/01/2013   WI7     
09/01/2013   OTH     
09/01/2013   MAC     
09/01/2013   WI8     
09/01/2013   WI8
```

We also have a dimension table which gives a full name to the above OS Type. The dimension_table looks some thing like below:

```
OS_TYPE OS_NAME
---------------

WI8                 Windows 8
WI7                 Windows 
MAC                 MAC
WXP                 Windows XP
NXP                 OTHER
PS3                 OTHER
POS                 OTHER

..
25 other types
```

I listed the top 10 OS types from main_table.

```
SELECT TOP 10 OS_TYPE 
FROM main_table 
ORDER BY measure1 
WHERE EVENT_DT BETWEEN '2013-09-01' AND current_date
```

I was able to get this working.

now, I would require some help updating the dimension table.

what I want to do is update the `dimension_table` with only top 10 `os_type` with the full names and rest `os_types` with name `"other"`.

hope I was clear..

please let me know.

thanks for reading through my request.

Comment: Your question is tagged "mysql".  Why is it using SQL Server/Sybase/Access syntax?

Comment: sorry about that. i just edited it. Any thoughts on how we can get this done..

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, the query would be something like this:

```
update dimensiontable
    set name = 'Other'
    where os_type in (SELECT TOP 10 OS_TYPE 
                      FROM main_table 
                      WHERE EVENT_DT BETWEEN '2013-09-01' AND current_date 
                      ORDER BY measure1 
                     ) ;
```

There is no guarantee that these are 10 distinct `OS_TYPE`s, but you state that this query returns what you want (even though it has a syntax error with the `order by` before the `where` clause).

However, I might expect the top 10 os types to be the ten most common ones.  If so:

```
update dimensiontable
    set name = 'Other'
    where os_type in (SELECT TOP 10 OS_TYPE 
                      FROM main_table 
                      WHERE EVENT_DT BETWEEN '2013-09-01' AND current_date 
                      ORDER BY count(*) desc
                     ) ;
```